# How to get the attribute of img tag?

Tags: webpack

How to get the attribute of img tag ?

I use `file-loader 6.0.0`

Append the image to the document like below:

```
import myImg from './images/myImg.jpg'

let element = document.createElement('div')
let image = new Image()
image.id = 'myImg'
image.src = myImg
element.appendChild(image)
document.body.appendChild(element)
```

When I log the width of the image, I got `0` by the code below:

```
const imageElement = document.getElementById(image.id)
console.log(imageElement.width)  // 0
```

Comment: Where are you setting the image's width and height? Do you have any CSS rules for it? Also, what does the method Image() do?

Comment: I didn't set them, About the Image(), code in the guide of [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images) **Loading Images** section

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `let image = new Image()` with `let image = document.createElement('img')`

one important thing to note `img` Element does not give the value of `width` unless you assign one